# How do I make changes in my project hosted on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, hosting, firebase-hosting

I usually make changes locally and push them to the git repository that firebase refers to. Then I run the command "firebase deploy" to deploy the project every time I make changes. Is this a good practice or Is there any other better or standard way to do it?

Here's my Github repo (that firebase refers to): https://github.com/sudo-nick16/web-dev-gwl/tree/main/main

My project is a very basic site built with HTML and CSS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is the de facto way of making updates to a web site that is hosted on Firebase.

There is a recent alternative that automatically runs such a deploy on a PR merge to Github by using Github Actions. To learn more about that and how to set it up, see the documentation on [deploying to live & preview channels via GitHub pull requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/github-integration).